# Mat-slide: one change triggers twice the subscription on valuechanges

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to synchronize a slidebar with a input text. It works fine. Also I want that the controls are updated when the blur event occurs (the `updateon: 'blur'` but I want also update immediately the value of the formcontrol, when the slidebar changes.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cakpgs

And now my problem: the valuechanges of my form is triggered twice, when I am changing the value of control via slidebar. When I change the value, I am doing a patchValue in the formular because I want to update the value immediately. And when the slidebar loses the focus (blur event), the valuechanges notification is triggered again.

How can I do, that the valuechanges of my formular only once is triggered, with the requirements that:

1. the formcontrol should be updated when the blur event occurs `updateon: 'blur'`
2. A change of the value via slidebar should be updated immediately

Answer (score 7):

I did the following:

```
this.form.valueChanges
.pipe(distinctUntilChanged((a, b) => JSON.stringify(a) === JSON.stringify(b)))
.subscribe(change => console.log(change));
```

So I check if the form really changes and if it does, then the subscriber is executed. Otherwise the subscriber is not called.

Comment: in my project, trigger twice because use ng-trim-value-accessor
.worked for me!

Comment: This is working as expected in Angular 10. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you already have formControls, then no need to do `[value]="AgeControl.value"`, let the value be updated through the formControl only... Since we want to detect change on each input (type: slider or text) and then replicate, we added a `(change)` for all the inputs.

To make the update more immediate, I added a third input right at the bottom of the form which makes these changes on each key stroke, more fun seeing such update with an `<input />`. Hope this is what you are looking for.

In your [existing stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cakpgs), make out your **hello-component.ts** to be:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
// Must import to use Forms functionality  
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormsModule, NgForm, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-hello-component',
  templateUrl: './hello-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./hello-component.component.css']
})
export class HelloComponentComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    // To initialize FormGroup  
    this.form = fb.group({
      'age': [null, { updateOn: 'blur' }]
    });
    this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(change => console.log(change));
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.AgeControl.setValue(10);
  }
  ngOnChanges() {
    console.log('change triggered');
  }

  public get AgeControl(): FormControl {
    return this.form.get('age') as FormControl;
  }
  onInputChange(event: any) {
    //value must change immediately
    this.form.patchValue({ 'age': event.target.value });
  }
  onSliderChange(event: any) {
    this.form.patchValue({ 'age': event.value });
  }
  onInputKeystroke(event: any) {
    this.form.patchValue({ 'age': event.target.value });
  }

}
```

In your [existing stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cakpgs), make out your **hello-component.html** to be:

```
<mat-slider thumbLabel tickInterval="1" min="1" [formControl]="AgeControl" (change)="onSliderChange($event)" max="100">
</mat-slider>
<br/>
<input [formControl]="AgeControl" (change)="onInputChange($event)">
<br/>
<input [formControl]="AgeControl" (change)="onInputChange($event)">
<pre>{{ form.value | json }}</pre>
<input [formControl]="AgeControl" (keyup)="onInputKeystroke($event)">
```

Comment: Here: `this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(change => console.log(change));` The subscriber function `console.log(change)` is called yet twice, when I am changing the value with the slider: in `onSliderChange` and in when the slider loses the focus

Comment: You are getting dual console.log with the code I shared?

Comment: Yes, when the slider lose the focus, comes another console.log